# Javascript : How to calculate the difference between two dates?

Tags: javascript

How to calculate the difference between two dates say date 1 is 28-04-2014 and date 2 is 30-04-2014 how to find the difference using javascript .

Comment: You could check out the library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it has many built-in operations to work on dates, including difference.

Comment: One of the many advantages with using ISO dates is that you can easily compare them (2014-04-28 < 2014-04-30). Where do you get the date from? Can you ask for them in a standard format?

Comment: i get the date from a datepicker in front end

Comment: Why reference a question that has a poor accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [datepicker from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) (or probably any other datepicker tool out there), you can chose what date format you want to recieve. In jQuery UI, use `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );` to get ISO 8601 dates, and then just compare them like this:

```
if ( dateOne < dateTwo ) ...
```

By using a standardized date format, you also know for sure that you will always be able to painlessly convert it to what ever format you want to display it in later.

Answer (score 1):

Vishwas' answer was actually pretty close, even though it's getting downvoted. You need to pass in a valid date format into the `new Date()` constructor.

```
var date1 = new Date("28-04-2014".split("-").reverse());
var date2 = new Date("30-04-2014".split("-").reverse());
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays, "number of days difference");
console.log(timeDiff, "in milliseconds");
```

The Date constructor needs dates in the form `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute etc etc..)` and takes arrays too.

Since your date format is in the form `day-month-year` we take your string and split it (by `-`) and reverse it to get `[year, month, day]`

Full Date Object Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date